# WPF DataGridCheckBoxColumn: how to hide the checkbox if the binding value is null?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I have a datagrid with a DataGridCheckBoxColumn binding to nullable bool. I'd like to hide the checkbox completely if the value is null. I tried the following trigger, but it doesn't work:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible at all? Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always two styles in a DataGrid, the `ElementStyle` and the `EditingElementStyle`, your style should be applied as `ElementStyle`, then you can still edit the checkbox but it won't be visible when not in edit mode if null. Also the three states need to be enabled.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding MyNullableBool}" IsThreeState="True">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: +1. This is the right answer, however it will work better if you you don't add IsThreeState="True", assuming the use case is that the user wants to only use checkboxes in the grid that are not bound to null.

Comment: It works partially for me. It does hide the checkbox if null. However, I also observed following problems: 1. My column is made read only. However, after I apply this style, the checkbox is no more read only. Actually, my binding property is a getter only, so I'm not sure how the checkable state is binding to. 2. The checkbox is now left aligned. It used to be centered. 3. How can I make this a reusable style? I have a lot of such columns and I don't want to repeat the same thing for every column. 4. I don't see any difference between setting or not setting IsThreeState=True.

Comment: You can define the style as a resource (`DataGrid.Resources`) and then just reference it: `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>`, where `myStyle` is the `x:Key` assigned to the style. Also set `Mode=OneWay` in the binding, it should not be editable (i even got an exception which forced me to do this when i removed the setter).

Comment: Okay, I made it work using resource - I didn't know I could assign a style to ElementStyle. The alignement problem can then be resolved by adding a setter of HorizontalAlignment property to Center in my style. Regarding the editing state, I already have Mode=OneWay defined and if I remove it I get an exception like you said. Somehow setting ElementStyle removes my IsReadOnly setting, and I can't set IsReadOnly in my style for the CheckBox because it's not a CheckBox property. The closest I can get is to set IsEnabled=False in my style. IsReadOnly is Column's property. How does it get reset?

Comment: I don't know why that is, i would just also use the `IsEnabled = false` approach.